# Recording streaming audio from online Flash and Silverlight sources

Tags: audio, flash, streaming, recording, silverlight

Is it possible to record streaming audio for a web site that uses a Flash Player or Silverlight player?  I thought at times it might be nice to record the live radio and play it back later, but the sites I've listened to are Flash/Silverlight, with no public WMA or ASMX link...

Thanks.

Comment: Info here...http://radio.about.com/od/recordstreamingaudio/Audio_Recording_Software_for_Online_Radio_Stations_and_Audio_Sources.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this for free using a few piece of open source software.  You would route the audio from your browser and plugins to a virtual output, then the output into recording software.

For the recording side, Audacity is a great open source recording application.  For routing the audio, you can use Soundflower.

This can also be accomplished using just Audio Hijack, which can be bought for 32 dollars:
http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/

Good luck!